# If I don't know where to ask my question, where on SE to ask for site recommendation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where do I ask where I should ask a question about something?

Comment: I'm unsure what you ask. Which part of the [help] or [tag:faq] didn't contain enough information to get you going?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you are trolling, but for the sake of getting an answer there...

If you are uncertain as to what site to post a question, you can ask here, on this site.

You do need to give enough information about what you want to ask (scope and topic at the least), and possibly the entire question then tag your question here with [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

Comment: "I suspect you are trolling" - hence my flag. Why not outright delete the question?

Comment: @Jan - suspicion != proof

Comment: I am not trolling, I was just completely lost in the web that is the mobile version of SE

Comment: @RasmusBeck - there are ways for asking for help. Hint: "deal with it" - not the best one ;)

Comment: Sorry, sometimes have a hard time expressing myself :/

Comment: @RasmusBeck "where to ask something about something" is not a real question.  If you want a site recommendation, then be specific.  What topic do you want to ask about, and what is your question, briefly about.

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you want to figure out which site your topic is on-topic.  You can find the complete list of sites [on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)

Then you just need to scan through the list to find where your questions *might* be on-topic.  Then once you have a site (or sites) where your question might be on-topic, then go look at the help center found at `/help` on every site.  There will be at least 2 pages on every site that explain [What questions can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Follow the instructions on those 2 pages as closely as possible to ensure you ask a good on-topic question.  It will help you have a good experience on the site and help you get the answers you seek.

If you are still stuck, you can of course come to Meta.SE (this site) and ask a **specific** question about where to ask your question.  As Oded suggests, make sure you use the [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)  and identify your topic.  It may also be helpful to **briefly** explain your question as well.